# Elegant way to find maximum range of a projectile launched from a height

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, velocity, projectile

> A projectile is launched from a height of $h$ and the initial velocity
> of $\sqrt{2ga}$. Find the maximum range achieved by the projectile in terms of $g$,$a$, and $h$.

I can go about the traditional way to solve this.

First finding the time it takes to reach the ground and then writing the range in terms of $\theta$, $g$,$a$, and $h$. Next, I can take the derivative to find the maximum.

**But, that it is a tedious and messy process. Is there any way to do this without such messy manipulation of algebra?**

Comment: I mean the simplest way is to just use the quadratic equation, you already know the roots of any quadratic formula without any algebraic manipulation.

Comment: *But, that it is a tedious and messy process. Is there any way to do this without such messy manipulation of algebra?* No. Calculus is Calculus,  no escape.

Comment: @Gert "No. Calculus is Calculus, no escape." Unfortunately in this particular case there is an escape. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: @Notwen You must be the **FIRST** to escape Calculus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We put $y = -h$ and $x = R$ in equation of trajectory.

$$-h = R\tan\theta - \frac{gR^2}{2u^2}\sec^2\theta$$
$$-h = R\tan\theta - \frac{gR^2}{2u^2}(1 + \tan^2\theta)$$

Now we have a quadratic equation in $\tan\theta$. As $\theta$ is real the determinant of quadratic equation should be always $\geq 0$. The problem is quite easily solved when you do $b^2 -4ac > 0$ for it.

Comment: Woahh it actually works, we end up with $ \frac ug\sqrt{u^2+2gh}$ for maximum range , Question how did you know we would get the maximum not the minimum with this method. Just want to know the thought process.

Comment: Thank You! That actually worked.